# On attached, `this.$` an empty object

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to observe added and removed dom nodes to my custom Polymer element without success. I've noticed that the `this.$` is an empty object.

```
  Polymer({
    is: 'dramatic-view',
    attached: function () {
      this._observer = Polymer.dom(this.$.contentNode).observeNodes(function (info) {
        console.log('kromid info', info);
      });
    }
  });
```

The callback is being called only once (even tho I change content afterwards) with the following strange parameters:

[image: console output]

I was following the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#observe-nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$` is a hash of elements in your template that have an `id` attribute (see [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding)).

So, for `this.$.contentNode` to exist, you need an element with `id="contentNode"` in your `<dom-module>`'s `<template>`, and it must not be inside a `dom-if` or `dom-repeat` template:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <content id="contentNode"></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Nodes created dynamically (i.e., those inside `dom-if` or `dom-repeat`) must be queried with `this.$$()` (e.g., `this.$$('#contentNode')`). If you're trying to set them up in the `attached` callback, you'll need to wait until *after* the nodes are stamped, which could be observed with `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender()`.

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[useDynamicContent]]">
      <content id="contentNode"></content> <!-- unavailable to this.$ -->
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',
      attached: function() {
        Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, function() {
          var contentNode = this.$$('#contentNode');
          if (contentNode) {
            contentNode.observeNodes(...);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

To trigger the node observer, use [Polymer's DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api-examples) like this:

```
Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(node);
Polymer.dom(this).removeChild(node);
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NbLGNQ)

**UPDATE** It seems you're integrating Polymer with Elm, and expecting to see the observer callback for node-changes made my Elm. You'll need to hook Elm's calls to `appendChild`/`removeChild` somehow so that it uses Polymer's DOM API.

Comment: I sense we are close.. adding `id` fixed the empty object, now the `<content>` is there. However, the callback is not being run when I change content.

Comment: How are you changing content?

Comment: It's being done within the `Elm` virtual-dom which I'm guessing is calling `appendChild`

Comment: See updated answer with Codepen demo. Not sure if it's possible, but you'll need to hook Elm's calls to `appendChild`/`removeChild` so that it uses Polymer's DOM API.

Comment: What what? Istn't this native-element functionality? Or observing children this just a Polymer api? Changing the Elm virtual-dom is not possible. It's part of the compiler.

Comment: Currently on Polymer 1.x, you need to use the Polymer.dom methods to do dom manipulation. However this is removed in Polymer 2.x to be as close to the platform as much as possible. You could give Polymer 2.x a try, though it is still in preview.